# PayPal IPN not sending notifications

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am currently developing an application with the PayPal online payment system and the PayPal IPN Message System is not sending the notification upon clicking the the Pay button.

I implemented the “PayPal Checkout” with the “Smart Payment Buttons” (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/#). I created a PayPal sandbox business account with which I test when I log in through my application. When testing with this account I get the data I need from PayPal (order id, amount, username of account, etc.) and I insert it in the database. Up to that point everything works fine, but I need a confirmation just to make sure (in case the web page freezes or goes down for some reason) the data was updated correctly in the database when the user pays the transaction through PayPal.

I decided to implement the PayPal IPN (Instant Payment Notification), a message system that notifies you of the events related to the PayPal transactions (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/). I used the sample code provided and modified it to fit my application (https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/C%23/paypal_ipn_mvc_core.cs). I used the Postman application and sent a sample IPN message (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/#ipn-protocol-and-architecture) to my IPN listener and it worked. For the last step I published in the Development Environment with my local code and tested it with Postman and it worked. Now here is where the problem starts, I used the PayPal button to pay a transaction with the sandbox account previously created, but I dint receive an IPN from PayPal. I also used the IPN Simulator (https://developer.paypal.com/developer/ipnSimulator/) to send a message from PayPal and I received a “IPN was sent and the handshake was verified” displayed in the PayPal website but the data was not updated in the database. When I check the IPN history in the PayPal website to check if an IPN was sent at some point, it was empty (no IPN messages where sent). This Development Environment where my application now resides is in Azure Portal.

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Receive()
    {
        PayPalRaw payPalRaw = new PayPalRaw();
        PayPalRaw payPalRaw1 = new PayPalRaw();

        try
        {
            // Get the received request's headers
            var requestheaders = HttpContext.Request.Headers["someKey"].ToString();
            payPalRaw.HeadersRaw = requestheaders.ToString();

            IPNContext ipnContext = new IPNContext()
            {
                IPNRequest = Request
            };

            //payPalRaw.HeadersRaw = ipnContext.Verification;

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ipnContext.IPNRequest.Body, Encoding.ASCII))
            {
                ipnContext.RequestBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
                //payPalRaw.BodyRaw = ipnContext.IPNRequest.Body.ToString();
                payPalRaw.BodyRaw = ipnContext.RequestBody.ToString();
            }

            _context.Add(payPalRaw);
            _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            //Store the IPN received from PayPal
            LogRequest(ipnContext);

            //Fire and forget verification task
            Task.Run(() => VerifyTask(ipnContext));

            //Reply back a 200 code
            return Ok();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {               
            payPalRaw1.HeadersRaw = ex.Message.ToString();
            payPalRaw1.BodyRaw = ex.Message.ToString();
        }

        _context.Add(payPalRaw1);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return StatusCode(200);
    }

    private void VerifyTask(IPNContext ipnContext)
    {
        try
        {
            var verificationRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr");

            //Set values for the verification request
            verificationRequest.Method = "POST";
            verificationRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            //Add cmd=_notify-validate to the payload
            string strRequest = "cmd=_notify-validate&" + ipnContext.RequestBody;
            verificationRequest.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;

            //Attach payload to the verification request
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(verificationRequest.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII))
            {
                writer.Write(strRequest);
            }

            //Send the request to PayPal and get the response
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(verificationRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
            {
                ipnContext.Verification = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            //Capture exception for manual investigation
        }

        ProcessVerificationResponse(ipnContext);
    }


    private void LogRequest(IPNContext ipnContext)
    {
        // Persist the request values into a database or temporary data store
    }

    private void ProcessVerificationResponse(IPNContext ipnContext)
    {
        if (ipnContext.Verification.Equals("VERIFIED"))
        {
            // check that Payment_status=Completed
            // check that Txn_id has not been previously processed
            // check that Receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
            // check that Payment_amount/Payment_currency are correct
            // process payment
        }
        else if (ipnContext.Verification.Equals("INVALID"))
        {
            //Log for manual investigation
        }
        else
        {
            //Log error
        }
    }
```

I think i missed some configuration or setting in my PayPal account or the PayPal IPN is waiting for some sort of handshake from the listener to finish the process.

Comment: did you enable IPN for your Merchant/Business Account in the Sandbox?